# 400 (Bad Request), POSTing a JSON object to a REST server

Tags: c#, json, post, httpwebrequest, bad-request

I've tried to make a post request but I keep on getting this error and I can't figure out what's wrong with the request.

Here is my code:

```
        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:8085/api/v1.0/events");
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        httpWebRequest.Headers["X-Appsensor-Client-Application-Name2"] = "myclientapp";
        httpWebRequest.Accept = "application/json";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

        httpWebRequest.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

        httpWebRequest.PreAuthenticate = true;

        httpWebRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            string json = "{ \"user\":{ \"username\":\"bob\"},"+
                            "\"detectionPoint\":{ \"category\":\"Access Control\",\"label\":\"ACE3\",\"responses\":[]}," +
                            "\"timestamp\":\"2018-02-18T18:54:58.506Z\","+
                            "\"detectionSystem\" {\"detectionSystemId\":\"localhostme\", \"ipAddress\":\"10.20.30.40\"}}";

            streamWriter.Write(json);
            streamWriter.Flush();
            streamWriter.Close();
        }

        var response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

Here is the body that the JSON object is using:
http://appsensor.org/docs/v2.3.0/api/ui/index.html#!/RestRequestHandler/resource_RestRequestHandler_addEvent_POST

What am I doing wrong and what mistake have I made?

EDIT:

Here is what the error says when it is displayed:

The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

Source Error:

Line 230:            }
Line 231:
Line 232:            var response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
Line 233:            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
Line 234:            {

Comment: As you get a 400 - bad request, it can be an error while processing the request at the server. Does calling a test function (or antoher function) without any parameters on your server work? Can you debug the server itself?

Comment: Did you inspect the results of the 400 response? A good API will return a payload telling you _why_ your request was bad. One assumes the JSON you provide is missing some information.

Comment: @Equalsk I have added the source error to the question

Comment: Your JSON is invalid; it's missing a colon after `detectionSystem`. It's always better to use something like JSON.NET to build up a JSON object and serialize it, rather than writing JSON by hand as a string.

Comment: @asherber I put the colon in, but I still have the same error.

Comment: I would try whittling down the request, ie. remove anything you can such as ` httpWebRequest.Headers["X-Appsensor-Client-Application-Name2"]` (just in case IIS Express doesn't like that) and simplify your JSON payload as much as possible.